# Custom $templateCache loader

Tags: angularjs

This is a question about template loading customization in `$templateCache`.

Goal is handling transport layer, exactly:

1. Ability to modify template url.
2. Ability to handle transport errors and timeouts.

How can be `$templateCache` loader modified with custom transport wrapper?

Prefferably at global application level, i.e. directives should't know about this modification.

Comment: i suppose you can use a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/$provide#decorator), as with any other service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`$http` interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#interceptors) for this. You could use the `request` interceptor to change the URL, and the `responseError` interceptor to deal with errors. A simple implementation is below, that you would have to change to exactly how you want the URL to be modified and how errors are handled.

```
app.factory('TemplateInterceptor', function($injector, $window, $q, $timeout) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
     // Test if is a template
     var isTemplate = config.url.match(new $window.RegExp("^/?templates/"));

     // Save in config, so responseError interceptor knows
     config.TemplateInterceptor = config.TemplateInterceptor || {};
     config.TemplateInterceptor.isTemplate = isTemplate;

     if (isTemplate) {
       config.url = '/modified-url' + config.url;
     }
     return config;
   },
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // Avoid circular dependency issues
      var $http = $injector.get('$http');

      // If a template, then auto-retry after 1 second
      return !rejection.config.TemplateInterceptor.isTemplate 
        ? $q.reject(rejection) 
        : $timeout(angular.noop, 1000).then(function() {
        return $http(rejection.config);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Registered as:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TemplateInterceptor');
});
```